# Mixins with John Resig's Class Syntax

Tags: javascript, prototype, mixins

I've implemented simple Mixin behaviour that is compatible with [John Resig's Class library](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). I'm asking for other JS folk to check the code and let me know if this is the way Mixin's normally work (I've not used them much before).

http://jsfiddle.net/aaronsnoswell/PHuvs/

If the code is incorrect, how should it work?

Comment: I don't think you need to `augment(Ninja, CanRun);` - it does already inherit from `Person` where `CanRun` is mixed in.

Comment: The jsfiddle link doesn't seem to be forking anymore... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that necessary to take in consideration style of mixin implementation.

For example if I make something like that:

```
if(ninja instanceof CanRun){
    document.write("yea");
}else{
    document.write("no");
};
```

Then should I get 'yes', or 'no'?

In your implementation mixin is not class. I don't know is it your target but in many languages mixin is a fully valued class except that it not allows create instances.

Comment: `CanRun` is an object, so `instanceof` will throw an exception. That's not how mixins work.

Comment: @Bergi For example in Ruby is_a (instanceof analogue) works with mixins properly like with classes. So if this code implements own understanding of mixin then it is ok. But in general case this is not so.